# How to call WP Theme Templates from WP Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, templates, list

Ok, you know when you're editing a page in Wordpress? You can change the page template under Page Attributes. How can I call a list of the current theme's page templates? I need that to use in my plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_page_templates`](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-admin/includes/theme.php.source.html#l159) returns an array of the page templates available for the current theme.